# Bash formating gone after update due to shellshock

Tags: bash, colors

Due to the shellshock case I updated my GNU Bash to the latest version 4.3.30.

Basically it works fine, however, I lost all formatings (ie prompt with current
working dir, colors, dir format etc) for the root user. I've still the standard
config in /etc/bash.bashrc which works fine for all other users. There's no extra
config file for the root user! Before the update the root user used the same
settings except that the prompt was turned to red color.

I've no idea left how to solve that issue. Does anybody else know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's changed in your update to alter your settings (perhaps /etc/bashrc), but you can add these into your local `.bashrc` file ($HOME/.bashrc for your user, /root/.bashrc for the root account).

```
# Coloured prompt with current directory
PS1="\[\e[1;31m\]\u@\h \[\e[1;33m\]:\W \$ \[\e[0m\]"

# Coloured ls output
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

# Other useful aliases
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../../'
alias l='ls -lFh'
alias ll='ls -lht'
alias la='ls -a
```

To change the colours just change the number after the `;` in the square brackets. A list of bash colours and other tips can be found [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

There are all sorts of options when it comes to customising your BASH prompt, have a look through the howto linked above, or just generally google around and you can find various examples.